# Utilizando un control tipo acordeón en Django Form - POST / submit no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, django-forms, accordion

Tengo un inconveniente con un Django `ModelForm` en el cual los datos `date_of_birth` y `creation_date` ambos de tipo `DateField` son incluidos en el request.POST, pero no son almacenados.

Este es mi formulario

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date' 

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # biography = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'country_of_origin': CountrySelectWidget(),
            'country_current_residence': CountrySelectWidget(),
             'date_of_birth': DateInput(), #datepicker
             'creation_date': DateInput(), #datepicker
        }

        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "gender", "enterprise_name",
        "country_of_origin", "city_of_origin", "country_current_residence",
        "city_current_residence", 'speak_languages', "phone_number",
        "address", "biography", 'description', "avatar", "date_of_birth", 
        "creation_date", 'entertainment_activities', "is_student", 
        "is_professor", "is_executive", "is_study_host", "is_hosting_host",)

        model = get_user_model()
```

La vista que efectúa la operación de POST es esta, hereda de `UpdateView`

```
class AccountSettingsUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UserProfileDataMixin, UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    success_message = "Perfil actualizado exitosamente"

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse("accounts:preferences",
                   kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs['slug']})

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """ Hook to ensure object is owned by request.user. """
        obj = super(AccountSettingsUpdateView, self).get_object()
        if not obj.id == self.request.user.id:
            raise Http404
        return obj
```

Cuando he probado haciendo un POST o guardando datos ejecutando esta vista, en mi template ingreso valores para los campos `date_of_birth` y `creation_date` pero estos campos no son modificados con el valor que les ingreso.

De acuerdo a esto, he querido sobreescribir el metodo `form_valid` en mi vista `AccountSettingsUpdateView` y me ha quedado asi:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save(commit=False)
    form.save()
    print("Se almaceno?")
    return super(AccountSettingsUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

La operacion de POST entra a form_valid tal como me lo indica el log en mi servidor:

```
06/Feb/2018 06:28:45] "GET /accounts/profiles/preferences/u/contactohostaynicom/ HTTP/1.1" 200 82893
Se almaceno?
[06/Feb/2018 06:28:52] "POST /accounts/profiles/preferences/u/contactohostaynicom/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[06/Feb/2018 06:28:52] "GET /accounts/profiles/preferences/u/contactohostaynicom/ HTTP/1.1" 200 83473
```

Entonces, he querido adicionar un punto de debug con `ipdb` en el metodo `form_valid` justo despues de que la sentencia form.save() es almacenada para detallar algún comportamiento:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    import ipdb
    form.save(commit=False)
    form.save()
    ipdb.set_trace()
    # messages.success(self.request, "Successfully created")
    print("Se almaceno?")
    return super(AccountSettingsUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Examino los campos `creation_date` y `date_of_birth` para mirar que en efecto son incluidos en el request

**`date_of_birth`**

ipdb> self.object.date_of_birth
    datetime.date(2018, 2, 15)

Examino el `request.POST` entero y puedo detallar que `date_of_birth` es incluido

```
ipdb> self.request.POST
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Y1ZnsMzkF2uhNaSSmCUt9pEmkSXDFx2hwQZvmO5XczNiLILj8TWn8ZsC6wOuQasM'], 'first_name': ['Bernardo Augusto'], 'last_name': ['García Loaiza'], 'gender': ['M'], 'date_of_birth': ['2018-02-15'], 'speak_languages': ['1', '2', '3'], 'entertainment_activities': ['4'], 'biography': ['Soy una persona que quiere ser mejor cada dia'], 'avatar': [''], 'country_of_origin': ['BA'], 'city_of_origin': ['Florencia la bella villa'], 'phone_number': ['+573124812992'], 'address': ['Parquexi'], 'city_current_residence': ['MedelLLIN  con el pug']}>
ipdb>
```

El mismo comportamiento aplica para el campo **`creation_date`** tambien

```
ipdb> self.object.creation_date
datetime.date(2018, 2, 8)
```

I check the `request.POST` whole and I can see that `creation_date` is included

```
ipdb> self.request.POST
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['w9c6vm3szmwwryPVfcsMBM3iJtQn8kcEQuPLTdI0TKTsxvJzxjamGOvHGzatkCN9'], 'enterprise_name': ['HOSTAYNI 2018 a salir'], 'creation_date': ['2018-02-08'], 'description': ['Somos una empresa innovadora joven con ganas de comernos el mundocsss'], 'avatar': [''], 'country_of_origin': ['CO'], 'city_of_origin': ['mEDELLIN'], 'phone_number': ['+573124812992'], 'address': ['lOMA lINDA']}>
ipdb>
```

La razón para que `creation_date` y `date_of_birth` no sean almacenados es por el widget que le asigno en la definición del formulario arriba.

Este widget es para poder tener un datepicker, se lo he quitado y entro la fecha manual en varios formatos y me funciona y graba las fechas.

Alguna idea para que en el formulario se pueda tener [un datepicker como este](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default)?

Comment: Quite los widgets en mi formulario `UserUpdateForm` y funcionó, las fechas  `creation_date` y `date_of_birth` ahora se graban, era la clase `DateInput` la que me impedía guardar en el `POST` debido a que enviaban con otro formato el contenido de las fechas, ahora mi problema se reduce a implementar un datepicker [como este](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default)